# Bundler not running rspec tests

Tags: ruby, rspec, bundle

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:spec chrisvh$ bundle exec rspec
Could not find i18n-0.6.9 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:spec chrisvh$ bundle install
--- ERROR REPORT TEMPLATE -------------------------------------------------------
- What did you do?

  I ran the command `/Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/bundle install`

- What did you expect to happen?

  I expected Bundler to...

- What happened instead?

  Instead, what actually happened was...


Error details

    Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/chrisvh/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client/updater.rb:32:in `initialize'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client/updater.rb:32:in `open'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client/updater.rb:32:in `open'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client/updater.rb:32:in `update'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client.rb:63:in `update'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client.rb:54:in `update_and_parse_checksums!'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher/compact_index.rb:63:in `available?'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher/compact_index.rb:15:in `call'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher/compact_index.rb:15:in `block in compact_index_request'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:154:in `use_api'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:331:in `block in api_fetchers'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:331:in `select'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:331:in `api_fetchers'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:336:in `block in remote_specs'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/index.rb:10:in `build'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:335:in `remote_specs'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:82:in `specs'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:56:in `__materialize__'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `map!'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `materialize'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:129:in `resolve_remotely!'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/installer.rb:195:in `resolve_if_need'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/installer.rb:70:in `run'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/installer.rb:22:in `install'
      /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/rbenv.d/exec/gem-rehash/rubygems_plugin.rb:27:in `install'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:106:in `run'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:173:in `install'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/exe/bundle:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.pre.1/exe/bundle:19:in `<top (required)>'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
      /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Environment

  Bundler   1.12.0.pre.1
  Rubygems  2.2.2
  Ruby      2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin15.0]
  GEM_HOME  /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  GEM_PATH  /Users/chrisvh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0:/Users/chrisvh/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  Git       2.7.1
--- TEMPLATE END ----------------------------------------------------------------

Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.

First, try this link to see if there are any existing issue reports for this error:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/search?q=Permission+denied+%40+rb_sysopen+-+%2FUsers%2Fchrisvh%2F.bundle%2Fcache%2Fcompact_index%2Frubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47%2Fversions&type=Issues

If there aren't any reports for this error yet, please create copy and paste the report template above into a new issue. Don't forget to anonymize any private data! The new issue form is located at:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/new
```

Apparently there is something very wrong with my bundler because I always get this error and in rails apps I'm forced to run sudo bundle install or something similar to get it working any information on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using 1.12.0.pre.1 version of bundler? Try latest stable v1.11.2

Comment: Sounds like you ran bundle as root previously, so now there are root owned files that you can't overwrite when running as a normal user

Comment: how would i got about fixing this?